# how to show hide element previce element and show one nested ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create this nested list to show and hide items but I want ask how can I show one list and hide other for example if user click on second subject will hide all open items

HTML

```
<ul>

    <li class="subject">List item 1 with subitems:
        <ul id="item">
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

        <li class="subject">List item 2 with subitems:
        <ul id="item">
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li class="subject">List item 3 with subitems:
        <ul id="item">
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
   // $("ul li").children().slideDown("slow");

    $(".subject").click(function(){
        $(this).find("#item").slideToggle("slow");
      });



})
CSS
#item
{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate ID is not a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(".subject").click(function(){
    $(this).find("#item").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/4WP2X/)

or

```
$(".subject").click(function () {
    $(this).find("#item").slideToggle("slow")
    .end().siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/rj2A8/)

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your markup. Your IDs should always be unique; otherwise use classes.

```
$(function(){

    $(".subject").click(function(){
        $('ul.item').not( $(this).find('ul.item') ).slideUp("slow");
        $(this).find('ul.item').slideDown('slow');
    });

});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/gz435/)